# Retrieve a segment of array in another array with a shallow copy and keeping the reference

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking for a way to cut a initial array from a specific index to another index

```
int[] array = {10,5,4,4,3,5,6};
int[] arrayCopy;
```

In this example, if I want to segment from **index[1]** to **index[4]**. The new array witch I store in `arrayCopy` should looks like this one `arrayCopy[] = {5,4,4,3}`. The constante problem is that my objectif is to keep reference of the original array.So if in `arrayCopy` I change a element il will change too in `array`

```
arrayCopy[] = {5,4,4,3}
arrayCopy[0] = 20 // arrayCopy[] = {20,4,4,3} and  array = {10,20,4,4,3,5,6};
```

I tried `Arrays.copyOfRange()` but it's a **deep copy** and `System.arraycopy()` make a **shallow copy** but it doesn't accomplish what I want.

I tried to make  my own method

```
public E[] fillArray(int[] _array, int begin, int end){
     int[] arrayTemp;    
     for ( int i = begin ; i <= end; i++ ) {        
           arrayTemp[i] = _array[i];
     } 
    return arrayTemp;            
}
```

**Output**

```
arrayCopy = fillArray(array,1,4);
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Note: I want to keep the array mechanism and not using an ArrayList or ...**

Comment: `Arrays.copyOfRange()` is **not** a deep copy, it's shallow. The difference between `Arrays.copyOfRange()` and `System.arraycopy()` is that `copyOfRange()` creates a new array for the result, while `arraycopy()` copies into an existing array, so to get a copy, you have to create that array manually. `copyOfRange()` is just a nice convenience method doing that for you. But, they are **both shallow**.

Comment: Can I still change the second array and the first array will change too

Comment: Never, no way, no how. Cannot be done. Not a plain arrays. This is where an `ArrayList` would work for you, because the [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) will do what you want: *Returns a view of the portion of this list [...] The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Can I change the second array and the first array will change too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643386/37643685#comment62766790_37643386)

There is no way for Java arrays to support that feature.

A Java array is an Object, so all arrays are independent objects, with their own memory structure for the array values.

<sup>*(This is unlike C, where an array is done by pointer manipulation, so a second pointer can point into the memory sequence of an array already referenced by another pointer.)*</sup>

If you want a sub-array of the first array, that is mapped such that changes to the sub-array is reflected in the main array, and vice-versa, you need something else.

One option is to use a `List`, and create the sub-list using [`subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive. (If `fromIndex` and `toIndex` are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

If you already have an array, you can wrap the array with a list using [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), then use the `subList()` as for any other list.

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

Note that `List` doesn't work for *primitive* types, so if your array is a primitive, you should use a [`Buffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) of the appropriate type (    `ByteBuffer`, `CharBuffer`, `DoubleBuffer`, `FloatBuffer`, `IntBuffer`, `LongBuffer`, `ShortBuffer`).

E.g. for an `int[]`, create the buffer using [`IntBuffer.wrap(int[] array, int offset, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#wrap-int:A-int-int-):

> Wraps an int array into a buffer.
>
> The new buffer will be backed by the given int array; that is, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa.

If you always access the array through the `IntBuffer`, by using [`IntBuffer.wrap(int[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#wrap-int:A-) to wrap the full array, your code could use either `IntBuffer` and not know if it is accessing the full array or the sub-array.

Comment: I'm new in programming and I know only array. So can I transform back the List to an array

Comment: I find this : Arrays.asList(array)

Comment: You can *copy* the values of the `List` into an array using [`toArray(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-).

Comment: Is this ok,   ` array = (Integer[]) Arrays.asList(arrayTemp).subList(begin, end).toArray();
`

Comment: The result will still be a **copy**, so going through a `List` to do it is excessive, when the same result can be obtained using `copyOfRange()`.

Comment: I'm lost, so there is no way to keep the reference of the original array even with the List

Comment: A `List` created using `Arrays.asList()` *is* referencing the array directly. A sub-list created using `subList()` from that list *is* referencing the sub-array directly. But, `toArray()` **copies** the result, **because an *array* is a separate Object with it's own memory structure.**

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
public static int[] fillArray(int[] _array, int begin, int end){
int[] arrayTemp = new int[end-begin+1];    
for ( int i = begin ; i <= end; i++ ) {        
      arrayTemp[i-begin] = _array[i];
} 
return arrayTemp;            
}
```

Comment: It makes it run (+1), but no explanation (-1), and does the same thing as `copyOfRange()` (-1), so not really helping OP do what he needs.

Comment: Yes, the second one change, but it's loose reference when you create a new array. I can not change the second and see the same change in the first.

Comment: Question statement does not clearly point out that changing second should change the original also. Do you want the original array to change?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to achieve.